# Compare two columns in two .csv files row by row with csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I have two large .csv files in which I would like to compare two columns row by row using either `csv DictReader` or maybe even `pandas`.

I need to check that all the rows of a particular column are identical in both files. I've seen some suggestions here, but none were working in my situation. The problem is incorrect iteration order over the second opened file, even though the files are identical.

I've done search and modify tasks really quick with `openpyxl`, but since the csv file size is several hundreds MB, converting the csv to excel even during runtime doesn't seem like a good decision.

Here is what I have right now code-wise:

```
import csv

class CsvCompareTester:

    work_csv_path = None
    test_csv_path = None

    @staticmethod
    def insert_file_paths():
        print()
        print('Enter the full absolute path of the WORK .csv file:')
        CsvCompareTester.work_csv_path = input()

        print('Enter the full absolute path of the TEST .csv file:')
        CsvCompareTester.test_csv_path = input()

    @staticmethod
    def compare_files(work_csv_file, test_csv_file):

        work_csv_obj = csv.DictReader(work_csv_file, delimiter=";")
        test_csv_obj = csv.DictReader(test_csv_file, delimiter=";")

        for work_row in work_csv_obj:
            for test_row in test_csv_obj:
                if work_row == test_row:
                    print('ALL CLEAR')
                    print(str(work_row))
                    print(str(test_row))
                    print()
                else:
                    print("STRINGS DON'T MATCH")
                    print(str(work_row))
                    print(str(test_row))
                    print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_tester = CsvCompareTester()
    csv_tester.insert_file_paths()

    with open(CsvCompareTester.work_csv_path) as work_file:
        with open(CsvCompareTester.test_csv_path) as test_file:
            csv_tester.compare_files(work_file, test_file)
```

How do I iterate over the .csv file rows while also being able to address particular rows and columns by key or value (which could definitely reduce the amount of useless iterations).
For some reason, in the code above, every row string from the first file doesn't match the other from the second file. Files are identical and have the same order of entries, I've double-checked it.
Why isn't the second file iterated as the first, from the beginning to its end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're looping over the files. The way you have it, an attempt is made to compare each row of the first file to *every* row of the second one. You instead need to fetch rows of them in lock-step — and a good way to do that is with the build-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

So do this instead:

```
    @staticmethod
    def compare_files(work_csv_file, test_csv_file):

        work_csv_obj = csv.DictReader(work_csv_file, delimiter=";")
        test_csv_obj = csv.DictReader(test_csv_file, delimiter=";")

#        for work_row in work_csv_obj:
#            for test_row in test_csv_obj:

        for work_row, test_row in zip(work_csv_obj, test_csv_obj):
            if work_row == test_row:
                print('ALL CLEAR')
                print(str(work_row))
                print(str(test_row))
                print()
            else:
                print("STRINGS DON'T MATCH")
                print(str(work_row))
                print(str(test_row))
                print()
```

By the way, even though it may no be causing any problems yet, I also noticed you're not opening the two files correctly as shown in the [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) documentation — you left out the `newline=''` argument.

Here's the proper way of doing that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_tester = CsvCompareTester()
    csv_tester.insert_file_paths()

#    with open(CsvCompareTester.work_csv_path) as work_file:
#        with open(CsvCompareTester.test_csv_path) as test_file:

    with open(CsvCompareTester.work_csv_path, newline='') as work_file:
        with open(CsvCompareTester.test_csv_path, newline='') as test_file:
            csv_tester.compare_files(work_file, test_file)
```